# »Folgende xxx zeigt ...« Punkt oder Doppelpunkt am Satzende?

Tags: punctuation

Setzt man im folgenden Beispiel einen Punkt oder einen Doppelpunkt am Satzende?

> Folgende Tabelle zeigt die Ergebnisse:
>
> ```
>  x | foo | bar
> ---+-----+-----
>  1 |  a  |  b
>  2 |  c  |  d
> ```
>
> *Tabelle 1: Die Ergebnisse*

Comment: Stilistische Freiheit.

Comment: Übrigens soll eine normgerechte Tabellenüberschrift („Tabelle 1: Die Ergebnisse“) _über_ der Tabelle stehen, wohingegen eine Bildunterschrift _unter_ der Abbildung platziert wird.

Comment: Ganz abgesehen von der typischen Ausgestaltungsform einer Tabelle mit genau drei waagrechten, parallelen Linien, die keine Linien schneiden ;)

Comment: @Loong: Dass die Tabelle eine Unterschrift hat und im Fließtext eingeführt wird, beißt sich sowieso.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ja, in dieser Form beißt es sich. Allerdings (um nun möglichen Missverständnissen vorzubeugen) soll in derartigen Berichten jede Tabelle eine Überschrift haben („Tabelle 1: Ergebnisse“) und auf jede Tabelle soll im Text ausdrücklich hingewiesen werden (dann jedoch besser nicht mit „folgende Tabelle zeigt“, sondern mit „Tabelle 1 zeigt“). Tabellen sollen möglichst in der Nähe der Textstelle stehen, in der sie erstmals erwähnt werden (es sei denn, die Anzahl an Textseiten ist sehr gering im Verhältnis zu den Tabellen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In deinem skizzierten Fall ein ganz klares *Jein*. Die Tabelle folgt direkt auf ihre Ankündigung. Man könnte also sagen**:** Die Tabelle ist einfach nur die Erklärung des eben im Satz angeschnittenen Themas.

Gleichzeitig ist es auch legitim, die Tabelle mit ihrer Nummer anzusprechen, und so zu tun, als wisse man nicht, wo auf der Seite sie auftauchen wird. Bei in TeX gesetzten Texten ist das vorteilhaft, da TeX selbst bestimmen möchte, wo es die Tabelle für am sinnvollsten hält; ebenso bei Fachartikeln, denn da möchte der Gestalter der Seite seine Freiheit haben.

Im Zweifel geht der Punkt also immer (könnte aber verlangen, dass der Satz umformuliert wird, damit er schöner klingt), der Doppelpunkt manchmal. In deinem Beispiel beides.

Answer (score 6):

Meinem Gefühl nach Doppelpunkt, da sich die Einleitung auf die kommende Tabelle bezieht.